# Small images and mobile for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image-size

We know that google likes high quality unique images. On the other side google likes fast load times (in particular on mobile).

What about showing two different dimensions images on desktop and mobile? Is it good? If yes than any wordpress plugins for that?